# vshaxe - how debug Javascript target in browser

Tags: javascript, debugging, ide, visual-studio-code, haxe

I'm pretty new in VS Code, and I'm looking for an automated solution to debug Haxe JavaScript project. 
A way to open or live-reload browser after compilation, like in FlashDevelop, Intelij.

Now, I use an external localhost server (MAMP), and after each build I reload the browser manually. It works, but is not very efficient.

Lets me know how you do that. ;)

For info, I'm on mac

Comment: What kind of application are you working on? Website? Game? Using any frameworks?

Comment: JS app in Browser, I use some externs and frontend libs (hexmachina, haxe-js-kit...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [MIX Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=varomix.mixliveserver) extension. You can give it a path to your `index.html`, for instance if it's `build/index.html`:

```
{
    "mix.rootPath": "build"
}
```

and then it will detect file changes and reload the page automatically. Note that this does not open the page in a browser, but a separate VSCode tab.

Comment: I finally understand my mistake, VS Code don't have internal server: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12080